# How to read $\frac{dy}{dx} $ when the term is only given?

Tags: calculus, terminology

When the term $\frac{dy}{dx}$ (not $\frac{d}{dx}y$) is only given, how to read the term between "the derivative $y$ with respect to $x$" and "the quotient of the differential $dy$ by the differential $dx$" for a differentiable function $y=f(x)$?

Comment: Both the notations are the same, and the origin of the notation, if I remember correctly was in fact from the 'quotient' interpretation of the derivative. In reality when you have $\frac{d}{dx}$ of a function, you are looking at the change in the function for an infinitesimal change in the input variable. Finding the instantaneous change-- that's the same as the derivative. Either way, you just read it "the derivative of y with respect to x." Though I've heard about the quotient interpretation, I don't think anyone ever actually reads it out that way. One similar common reading is "dy by dx."

Answer (score 7):

I think that should read "the derivative of y with respect to x". I've never heard of the saying "the quotient of the differential dy by the differential dx".

$\frac{d}{dx}$ is just the derivative operator. It means taking the derivative of whatever follows. So that is to say, although $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and $\frac{d}{dx}y$ are written differently, they actually calculate and mean the same thing.